# PHP Shopping Cart

Tags: php

I am trying to add a product to my shopping cart.

I am getting an error saying:

**Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in**

It is telling me I am getting an error for the following code:

```
function isInCart($id) {
if (!empty($_SESSION['sess_uid']['cart'])) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['sess_uid']['cart'] as $report) {
        if ($report['reportID'] == $id) {
            // Report ID found in Cart
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Looped through cart, ID not found
    return false;
} else {
    // Cart empty
    return false;
}
}
```

The particular line from the above that is flagging the error is:

```
foreach ($_SESSION['sess_uid']['cart'] as $report) {
```

I am also getting the following error message:

**Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in**

The code this relates to is the following:

```
function addToCart($id) {
$report = getReportByID($id);
$author = $report['userID'];

if (!empty($report)) {
    // Got the report
    if (!empty($_SESSION['sess_uid']['cart'])) {
        if (!isInCart($id) && !isOwner($author) && !hasPurchased($id)) {
            array_push($_SESSION['sess_uid']['cart'], $report);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        $_SESSION['sess_uid']['cart'] = array();

        if (!isInCart($id) && !isOwner($author) && !hasPurchased($id)) {
            array_push($_SESSION['sess_uid']['cart'], $report);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
} else {
    // Unable to get report by ID
    return false;
}
}
```

The particular line of code from the above that is flagging the error is:

```
array_push($_SESSION['sess_uid']['cart'], $report);
```

The code below is what gets my reports to populate the store

```
<?php

function getReportByID($id) {
$conn = new mysqli(localhost, root, DBPASS, DBNAME);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM reports WHERE reportID = '" . $conn->real_escape_string($id)."';";
// Performs the $sql query on the server
$report = $conn->query($sql);

return $report->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}

?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried saving $_SESSION['sess_uid']['cart'] to a variable?

Comment: No I haven't, I will have a go with your suggestion and see how it goes!

Comment: what happens in `getReportByID()`? does it return an array?

Comment: I will add getReportID to my code above to let you see, it gets reports from my database which is the items that users can purchase from the store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think this wil help:
it typcast your session as an array so even when the session is empty you dont get an error

```
foreach ((array)$_SESSION['sess_uid']['cart'] as $report) {
```

let me know if this fix the error?

Comment: @user3296793 thanks for letting me know, foreach always give an error when the inputed var is empty (becouse hee needs an array)